# How $\lim_{n \in N,n \to \infty} \frac{ \lfloor rn \rfloor }{n} = r$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\lim_{n \in N,n \to \infty} \frac{  \lfloor rn \rfloor  }{n} = r$

I know that for every r, real number there exists a sequence of rational numbers. But in above how left side limit = r. Is it tends to o? i did not understand how it tends to r. Kindly elaborate

Comment: Essentially this works because the fractional amount removed by the floor function makes less and less difference with larger numbers, i.e., when $r\mapsto rn$. So for large $n$, $\lfloor rn \lfloor \approx rn$.

Comment: nice...........

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$
\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x \leq \lfloor x \rfloor+1, \quad \mbox{when } x \geq 0
$$
yields
$$
rn - 1 \leq \lfloor rn \rfloor \leq rn 
$$
Dividing all sides by $n$ will give you the limit.

Comment: oh yes! understood. thank you

Comment: You can make the upper part of the inequality strict: $\lfloor x\rfloor \le x < \lfloor x \rfloor +1$ but in this case it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Sandwich theorm!

Answer (score 2):

Let $rn=I+f,\; 0\le f<1$

As $n\to\infty, I\to\pm\infty$ according as the sign of $r$

$$\dfrac{[rn]}n=\dfrac I {\dfrac{I+f}r}=r\cdot\dfrac1{1+\dfrac fI}$$